# The method 'play' isn't defined for the type 'AudioCache'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-web, dart-packages

issue The method 'play' isn't defined for the type 'AudioCache'.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/src/audio_cache.dart';

```
void main() {
runApp(XylophoneApp());
}

class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            final player = AudioCache();
            player.play('note1.wave');
          },
          child: Text('click me'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
 );
}
```

}

Answer (score 28):

The code below is no longer valid from audioplayers v1.0.1

```
final player = AudioCache();
player.play('note1.wave');
```

Instead U can do this

```
final player = AudioPlayer();
//
player.play(UrlSource('note1.wave'));

// If file located in assets folder like assets/sounds/note01.wave"
await player.play(AssetSource('sounds/note1.wave'));
```

consider look in [migration guide](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/migration_guide.md) from audioplayers

Answer (score 5):

`AudioCache` is dead because of confusion in name. Now, if you want to play an `audio file` from `assets` you can use this.

```
// add this in imports
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

// play audio
final player = AudioPlayer();
player.play(AssetSource('note1.wav'));
```

Use this instead of `AssetSource` if you want don't want to play from assets.

1. `UrlSource`: get the audio from a remote URL from the **Internet**
2. `DeviceFileSource`: access a **file in the user's device**, probably selected by a file picker
3. `AssetSource`: play an asset bundled with your app, normally within the **assets** directory
4. `BytesSource` (only some platforms): pass in the bytes of your audio directly **(read it from anywhere)**.

You can see more from `audioplayers`  [documentation](https://UrlSource:%20get%20the%20audio%20from%20a%20remote%20URL%20from%20the%20Internet%20DeviceFileSource:%20access%20a%20file%20in%20the%20user%27s%20device,%20probably%20selected%20by%20a%20file%20picker%20AssetSource:%20play%20an%20asset%20bundled%20with%20your%20app,%20normally%20within%20the%20assets%20directory%20BytesSource%20(only%20some%20platforms):%20pass%20in%20the%20bytes%20of%20your%20audio%20directly%20(read%20it%20from%20anywhere).)

Answer (score 1):

if you faces this problem with ***Tharwat Samy course*** , then here is the solution for the problem :

- note that :

audioplayers 4.0.1

flutter 3.7.10

- change this code :

  ```
   Number(
   image: 'assets/images/numbers/number_one.png',
   enName: 'one',
   jpName: 'Ichi',
   sound: 'assets/sounds/numbers/number_one_sound.mp3'),
  ```

to :

```
    Number(
    image: 'assets/images/numbers/number_one.png',
    enName: 'one',
    jpName: 'Ichi',
    // remove 'assets/' from audio path .
    sound: 'sounds/numbers/number_one_sound.mp3'),
```

- do this change with all audio files paths .

2. also change player code from :

   ```
    AudioCache player = AudioCache(prefix:'assets/sounds/numbers/');
    player. Play(number.sound);
   ```

to :

```
    final player = AudioPlayer();
    player.play(AssetSource(number.sound));
```

or you can also add path directly by :

```
    final player = AudioPlayer();
    // don't forget to delete 'assets/' from the path 
    player.play(AssetSource('sounds/numbers/number_one_sound.mp3'));
```

from one of Tharwat samy students 
provided by : AMG ,
https://web.facebook.com/mohamed.amged.351

Answer (score 1):

```
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('My Xylophone'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
    ),
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            final player = AudioPlayer(); //insted of AudioCache() use AudioPlayer()
            player.play(AssetSource('note1.wav'));
          },
          child: Text('Click Here'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be the issue with your import. Do import this

import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

If the issue still exists, then use an older version of it.
I think version 0.19.0 should work for you.

Comment: thank you , previous version worked properly

Comment: Great. Please mark my answer to be correct. So others can use it as a verified answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Raj if You are doing LinkedIn course by London App Brewery and Angela Yu then an exact version that would work perfectly would be 0.10.0

> audioplayers: 0.10.0

It's the one used by Angela and it worked perfectly for me :-)
Wouldn't try it though if not for @Zain Basharat Ali advice.
Thanks for Your tip! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses AudioCache instead of AudioPlayer();

```
final player = AudioCache();
player.play('note1.wave');
```

You should change to ...

```
final player = AudioPlayer();
player.play('note1.wave');
```

Answer (score 0):

`AudioCache` Class is meant to manage cache storage where it saves the audio files temporarily. [Check AudioCache Class from Source Code](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/packages/audioplayers/lib/src/audio_cache.dart).

`AudioPlayer` Class already uses `AudioCache` Class and implements it in the method `setSourceAsset` for files saved in the `assets` folder, this method saves it to the cache.

Then, notice it won't play it automatically, you need to play it manually.

Since the `play()` method returns the method `resume()` [Check AudioPlayer Class from Source Code](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/packages/audioplayers/lib/src/audioplayer.dart), you can play it manually by executing the method `resume()` directly.

---

**Example:**

*For the file 'assets/note1.wav'.*
*assets/ is prefixed by default*

```
final player = AudioPlayer();
await player.setSourceAsset('note1.wav'); 
await player.resume();`
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are following Flutter Boot Camp by Dr. Angela Yu on Udemy
Here is The Solution that I've incorporated and get it Done Correctly

```
AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
player.play(AssetSource('note2.wav'));
```

Answer (score -1):

**You cannot use AudioCache(); with player.play('note1.wave'); This is because the method 'play' is not defined in the AudioCache class.**

Use the following class:

```
final player = AudioPlayer();
player.play(AssetSource('note1.wave'));
```

But make sure that you have added the assets for the audio track to the pubspec.yaml file:

```
 assets:
   - assets/sounds/
```

Or if the first one doesn't work try this one

```
assets:
  - assets/sounds/note1.wave
```