# flutter audioplayer initState();

Tags: android, ios, flutter, audio, mobile

how to reuse sound in init State() every second?

```
  _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: widget.time), (timer) {
      setState(() {
audioPlayer.play(AssetSource('audios/sound1.wav'));
});
```

is there some mistake in this part

Is there a play function in audioCache?

I use audioplayer ^4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
final player = AudioPlayer();
await player.play(AssetSource('audios/sound1.wav'));
```

Also, you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72654603/the-method-play-isnt-defined-for-the-type-audiocache) for other solutions as well.